# Function not working on Truffle, but works on Remix

Tags: truffle, cpp-ethereum

I have a contract that does the following:

- It maintains a list of items, which stores the name, id, sold status etc.
- I have a function, `createItem`, which creates these items and requires the name of the item.
- I have a function, `purchaseItem`, this function sets the items[_id].sold = true.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0; 

contract TradeCoin {
    uint public count = 0; 

    struct Item {
        uint id; 
        string name;
        bool sold; 
        uint unit;
        address seller;
        address buyer;
    }

    constructor() {
        createItem('Bedframe', '1');
        createItem('Gaming Chair', '1');
        createItem('Dining Table', '1');
    }

    mapping(uint => Item) public items;

    function createItem(string memory _name, uint _unit) public {
        count++;
        items[count] = Item(count, _name, false, _unit, msg.sender, address(0));
    }

    function buyItem() public {
    }

    function purchaseItem(uint _id) public {
        items[_id].sold = true;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I am able to call createItem, but I am unable to call purchaseItem in the truffle console.

This is the error I am getting back which isn't very helpful

```
truffle(development)> Uncaught Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  data: {
    '0xbad383e14adc1990474ef7426b3b9948601896f605094db59979153102f379d5': { error: 'revert', program_counter: 98, return: '0x' },
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachwOodBT/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n' +
      '    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganachwOodBT/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n' +
      '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)',
    name: 'RuntimeError'
  },
  hijackedStack: 'Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
    '    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:1)\n' +
    '    at /home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:1\n' +
    '    at /home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:107:1\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)\n' +
    '    at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/jennifer/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:47)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)\n' +
    '    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:537:15)\n' +
    '    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1340:12)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)'
}
```

I know that items[0] exist because I created that in the constructor. I was even able to get items[0]. I tried to recreate this in Remix, I can call purchaseItem without any issue.

I thought maybe the deployed contract is out of sync, so I tried deploying it multiple times and I know it does get updated. Because if I changed the parameter of purchaseItem to 0 parameter, it throws an error saying that `purchaseItem has 0 arguments but 1 was given`.

I then made an even simpler function called `buyItem`, which does nothing. Even that is throwing this error. This makes me think it's not an issue with the function itself but how it's being called?

**Details on Migration/Test**

**1_initial_migration.js**

```
    /* eslint-disable no-undef */
    const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
    
    module.exports = function (deployer) {
      deployer.deploy(Migrations);
    };
```

**1_deploy_contracts.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const TradeCoin = artifacts.require("./TradeCoin.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(TradeCoin);
}
```

Here is how the Transaction shows up in Gnache
[image]

It also appears that it's not an out-of-gas issue, which some people suggested could cause this error sometimes.

Truffle Config

```
module.exports = {
  contracts_build_directory: "./src/contracts/",
  networks: {
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.10",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
       optimizer: {
         enabled: true,
         runs: 200
       },
       evmVersion: "byzantium"
      }
    }
  },

};
```

**Truffle Debugger Output**
I also tried stepping through the code using Truffle Debugger. It appears that there are 38 steps. And it fails on the 38th. I am not really sure what the instructions do and why after DUP1, it would do revert.

[image: This is what I have]

What could the issue be? Any advice on where I should look for debugging. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`items[0]` doesn't exist, you increment `count` before adding the item to your mapping, so the first ever item will be `items[1]`.

This is what I get on Remix when I call `items(0)`
[image]

You also have a very wide range as your solidity version, you might want to narrow it down to avoid remix and truffle running with versions that are too far apart that could trigger compatibility issues.

Comment: Good catch. But even if I did purchaseItem(1), it still does not work. Also, doesn't seem to explain why buyItem, which is an empty function would cause erroring out.

Comment: True. Can you add a bit more details about your Truffle migration/test? If it works with both of us on Remix but it does not on Truffle, the issue is probably in there.

Comment: Alright, updated the question to include the migration code, its p simple. I don't have any tests. Maybe I should write some.

Comment: Did you check the solidity version of your Truffle config? Is it the same (at least the major version) as the one you used in Remix?
Providing your truffle config could help as well in this case

Comment: Yeah, I checked. They are the same, version 0.8.10. I added the truffle config in the question

Comment: Are you using the Truffle console to communicate with your contract? If yes, can you paste what command do you write?

Comment: Yeah, I am using truffle console. 

This is the command that I used 
TradeCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) { instance.purchaseItem(1); });

Comment: Okay, an interesting find. I noticed that the ABI generated using truffle is quite different from the ABI generated using Remix. Not sure if that matters. But I am now trying to use the web3.eth.Contract API to deploy the contract in the client code rather than using Truffle, and see what happens

Comment: You can also tell Remix to connect to your Ganache and try to deploy the contract from there. It could tell you if the problem is with the truffle console, or with the truffle deployment. Although generating a different ABI from the same code is kinda weird, so it's probably the latter.